# Docker container reachable from the inside but not the outside

Tags: docker, flask

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to deploy a flask app using docker container but I cannot access it via http://host_ip:port.
Here's my flask code :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Flask app'



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0')
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

I build image using :
docker build --tag python-docker .
and run it using:
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 python-docker

I'm able to get a response when I : curl localhost:5000
but not when trying to reach it from the outside

PS : I looked on previous posts about this issue but none has helped me.

Comment: What is "the outside"?

Comment: from the web, by visiting http://host_ip:5000

Comment: Do you have the external ip assigned to the host or a port 5000 forwarded to the host by the router at the edge of your network? Do you have any sort of firewall and if so is it configured to allow such traffic?

Comment: jabbson how can I know, I'm using a new ubuntu server

Comment: I have port 5000 open

Comment: I have enabled port 5000 using ufw allow, but I can't see it when using nmap

Comment: How can you know? Well, you either do or you don't :). Start with understanding where  (which device) this external ip you are trying to reach is assigned - on your host OR on another device.

Comment: I don't think it's another device, it must be my host, it's the ip I connect to with ssh command

Comment: You can check with either `ip addr` or 'ifconfig' on the host.

Comment: these commands show some other ips but not my actual external ip. but if I do : curl ifconfig.me I get my external ip

Comment: When you run `curl ifconfig.me` you don't get you external ip, instead you get to know what ifconfig.me thinks your external ip is, there is a difference. If you do not see the external ip in the list of ips for the interfaces on your host, that means you have a layer 3 routing device in the network [likely router/modem], that performs the network address translation as your traffic leaves the network and goes out to the internet.

Comment: Which I as it now seems rightfully assumed in the comment number 3. Now to make this work you need to configure said device [router/modem] to perform port forwarding/mapping for the external ip address that is assigned to it to forward a desired port of your choosing to be mapped to the port 5000 on the host. Easy peasy lemon squeezy.

Comment: Doesn't -p 5000:5000 already do the forwarding process? Also when I run: docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started it works, I can visit http://my_public_ip on the web

Comment: -p 5000:5000 does forward from the host to the container, but something must be forwarding from external ip to the internal ip of the host (since as you said this external ip isn't assigned to your host directly). If port 80 works that means that port 80 is forwarded to your host already [likely, since I do not know your infrastructure setup].

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. Could you guide me on how to forward from the external IP to the internal IP of the host?

Comment: This very much depends on what kind of device you are running at the edge of your network and whether you have access to its configuration. If you have a router or a modem or another layer 3 device that acts as a gateway between you internal network and the internet, you need to access this device's configuration page and find where you can setup port forwarding.

Comment: My server is a fresh google cloud VM . I can't find a solution on the internet, isn't there a command to do the forwarding?

Comment: Well, you could've started with that or indicated in the tags at least :) as this changes everything. Forget everything I was saying about port forwarding. You need to: a) verify the Cloud VPC Firewall is allowing port 5000 with `gcloud compute firewall-rules list | grep 5000` (or check in the Web UI) and b) make sure the ports are open with `sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 5000` on the host.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9910/docker-proxy. This is what I get, I think it's open and listening

Comment: this part is good, what about the Cloud Firewall?

Comment: That was the issue, thank you very much. It's working now after opening the port on google firewall

Comment: Great, glad it worked!